# OpenShift installing scipy with pip - Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, pip, openshift

I'm having trouble deploying an app on OpenShift.

The app requires scipy but every time I try to pip install scipy the ssh connection invariably ends in "Connection to  closed by remote host."

I've tried a few things : 
export TMOUT=

.openshift_ssh/config :
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 99999
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 99999

Launching the install in a tmux, and re-attaching it if the connection is interrupted. Turns out the tmux also gets killed apparently.

Has anyone successfully installed scipy on OpenShift, or any other package that would require a long compile time ?

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Try to use `easy_install` instead of `pip`.

Comment: I also have this problem.